# DRY caching in C

Tags: c, dry, memoization

I'm looking to DRY out the following C code:

```
if (i < SIZE_OF_V) {
    if (V[i])
        K = V[d];
    else
        K = V[d] = (expensive complicated call);
} else {
    K = (expensive complicated call);
}
```

Any advice? A local macro would work, but I'd prefer a more modern alternative.

Comment: I didn't get the word `DRY` can you please ?

Comment: @Omkant DRY: "Don't Repeat Yourself"

Comment: Ohh haha ... such an Abbreviation .. Thanks @ascii-lime

Comment: @Charles Keep it as it is. ;) I find your code easier to understand than the one by alestanis below.

Comment: @Cthulhu: The trouble is that the marked section of the code is very complicated, and I'm concerned that having it in two places will eventually result in one being updated but not the other.

Comment: @Charles Why don't you put it in a function then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do

```
if (i < SIZE_OF_V && V[i]) {
    K = V[d];
} else {
    K = (expensive complicated call);

    if (i < SIZE_OF_V)
        V[d] = K;
}
```

You can also put your `expensive complicated call` in an external function and callit from two places inside your `if` conditions:

```
int myExpensiveAndComplicatedCall() {
    // Do things
}

if (i < SIZE_OF_V) {
    if (V[i])
        K = V[d];
    else
        K = V[d] = myExpensiveAndComplicatedCall();
} else {
    K = myExpensiveAndComplicatedCall();
}
```

Comment: There's still the minor repetition of `i < SIZE_OF_V` but you could remove that too by storing the result of that comparison in a variable before the first `if()`.

Comment: @caf will that really be better than just evaluating an int comparison one more time? ;)

Comment: It almost certainly comes to the same thing after compilation, it depends on how fundamentalist the OP is about DRY ;)